# Can't get Django REST Swagger to work with routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I have a Django REST Framework project and I'm trying to generate Swagger documentation. In my URL's file, however, I use a router and that doesn't seem to work very well with Swagger. I followed the instructions in [this discussion](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/479) and here's what I got:

This works perfectly:

```
router = CustomRouter(
    schema_title='My API',
    schema_renderers=[renderers.CoreJSONRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer],
    trailing_slash=False
)
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, base_name='user')
router.register(r'foos', FooFieldViewSet)
router.register(r'bars', BarViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^session-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
]
```

And I get the expected page:

[image: expected page]

If I add `SwaggerUIRenderer` to the `schema_renderers` list, however, it doesn't work anymore:

```
router = CustomRouter(
    schema_title='My API',
    schema_renderers=[renderers.CoreJSONRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer],
    trailing_slash=False
)
# ...
```

I get this page:

[image: You do not have permission to perform this action]

What am I doing wrong??

**UPDATE**

If I add `?format=swagger`, I get:

```
/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango110Warning: django.core.context_processors is deprecated in favor of django.template.context_processors.
  return f(*args, **kwds)

[22/Jul/2016 09:00:10] "GET /?format=swagger HTTP/1.1" 403 3688
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 174, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 172, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 160, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)
  File "/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/renderers.py", line 18, in render
    data = json.loads(codec.dump(data))
  File "/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openapi_codec/__init__.py", line 34, in dump
    data = generate_swagger_object(document)
  File "/home/vagrant/ve/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openapi_codec/encode.py", line 8, in generate_swagger_object
    parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(document.url)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'url'
[22/Jul/2016 09:00:10] "GET /?format=openapi HTTP/1.1" 500 81912
```

Comment: It seems like you are not sending the `Authorization` header with this request.

Comment: But how could adding `SwaggerUIRenderer` cause the `Authorization` header to get lost while using the default Browserable API? I'm not sure I was clear, the **ONLY** difference between the 2 scenarios is this one item in the list of `schema_renderers`. In the first scenario, everything works and I get no 403 error, so the `Authorization` header is clearly being sent properly. If I add the `SwaggerUIRenderer`, however, the Browserable API breaks and starts giving me 403. Besides, even in the broken scenario, my username still appears in the top bar, so I'm logged in.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, the SwaggerUIRenderer does not override the default browsable API of the root view (html), so you have to specify the `format` query parameter to switch between renderers.

For example:

`http://localhost:8000/?format=swagger` -> Swagger UI interface

`http://localhost:8000/?format=openapi`-> Swagger/OpenAPI JSON spec

`http://localhost:8000/?format=corejson` -> CoreAPI CoreJSON

As for the 403, sounds like either an authentication config or you are not logged in.

Alternatively, remove the schema attributes of the router, and instead create a separate view that returns the schema.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I know about the `format` parameter, but the thing is, just by adding the Swagger renderer, the default Browserable API breaks and gives me 403. I suppose Swagger is just an extra option and I should still be able to access the Browserable API, right? But I can't. My username still appears at the top bar, I have the option to logout, but I get the 403 error in the json instead of the expected list of endpoints.

Comment: If I create a separate view I don't get any errors but the endpoints that are added using the router simply don't show up.